# PHP SOAP with self signed certificate

Tags: php, soap, ssl, ssl-certificate

I'm having some issues calling a websevrice in php with the SoapClient. The webservice has a self signed cert.

This is running on wamp 2 on windows 7

Here is the code:

```
<?php
    $client = null;

    $wsdlLocation = "https://uat.xxxx.com/wsdl/customer.wsdl";
    $cert = 'c:\Projects\***\certname.cer';
    $client = new SoapClient($wsdlLocation, array('local_cert' => $cert));

?>
```

I get the following error:

Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [WSDL] SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'https://uat.xxx.com/wsdl/customer.wsdl' : failed to load external entity "https://uat.xxx.com/wsdl/customer.wsdl" in C:\Projects**\auth\test.php:10 Stack trace: #0 C:\Projects***\auth\test.php(10): SoapClient->SoapClient('https://uat.ser...', Array) #1 {main} thrown in C:\Projects**\auth\test.php on

line 10

Any clues? I have tried full and relative paths. I am curious about the fact i am told to use this .cer file and not a .pem file? I have also added the certificate as a trusted authority in the certificate store.

Comment: I would also note that I can view the wsdl in IE fine,although I have to tell chrome to ignore that fact it is self signed.

Comment: According to a comment in the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/soap.requirements.php), if you use https, SOAP modules need to be configured with openssl.